# Having trouble connecting to Internet

Tags: windows, firefox

I am getting that same message:

> [Rocket Tab] DNS look up for "d2e24t2jgcnor2.webhostoid.com" failed.
>   no such host is known!

I have unchecked the proxy and it still does not work! What else can I do? Is there an IP address that I should put?

Comment: A little more information to go on would be nice

Comment: Looks like Rocket Tab is the culprit here. http://superuser.com/questions/814706/all-requests-seem-to-be-going-through-something. I'd recommend uninstalling it and additionally performing a malware scan using Malwarebytes Anti-malware

Answer (score 0):

1. hit window key + R  an then type msconfig
2. go to startup tab and disselect all press apply
3. go to services tab and check the selection hide windows services
4. uncheck all the leftover services and press apply
5. reboot
6. open your browser ex. Chrome and go to  settings
7. scroll down and press "show advanced" link
8. scroll again to the bottom and press the "reset settings" button 
   close chrome and restart again.

Check if it works

The other way is to download the Malwarebytes Anti-malware and make a scan to your pc. :-)

Comment: Other malware scanners are available.

Comment: This one works for me . An other one that i trust is Spybot .

Comment: Rocket Tab is a known problem (malware).